# Listing everything else than *{.tex, .aux} by ls

Tags: unix, ls

**How can you `ls` everything else the the files `*{.tex, .aux}`?**

I run unsuccessfully

```
ls -I".tex"
```

Comment: Can someone s/else than/except for/g?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@sth](https://superuser.com/a/32522/39752)'s answer, I finally found an `ls` command which works with a prefix selection glob pattern (there the hide option doesn't work); consider:

```
touch MyDocument{.aux,.auxlock,.bbl,.bcf,.blg,.log,.out,.pgf-plot.gnuplot,.run.xml,.tex,.toc}
touch YourDocument{.aux,.auxlock,.bbl,.bcf,.blg,.log,.out,.pgf-plot.gnuplot,.run.xml,.tex,.toc}

ls                                # list all
# MyDocument.aux               YourDocument.aux
# MyDocument.auxlock           YourDocument.auxlock
# MyDocument.bbl               YourDocument.bbl
# MyDocument.bcf               YourDocument.bcf
# MyDocument.blg               YourDocument.blg
# MyDocument.log               YourDocument.log
# MyDocument.out               YourDocument.out
# MyDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot  YourDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot
# MyDocument.run.xml           YourDocument.run.xml
# MyDocument.tex               YourDocument.tex
# MyDocument.toc               YourDocument.toc

ls MyDocument.*                   # prefix search glob only, works fine
# MyDocument.aux      MyDocument.bcf  MyDocument.out               MyDocument.tex
# MyDocument.auxlock  MyDocument.blg  MyDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot  MyDocument.toc
# MyDocument.bbl      MyDocument.log  MyDocument.run.xml

ls --hide='*.tex'                 # works if no search glob is used
# MyDocument.aux      MyDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot  YourDocument.blg
# MyDocument.auxlock  MyDocument.run.xml           YourDocument.log
# MyDocument.bbl      MyDocument.toc               YourDocument.out
# MyDocument.bcf      YourDocument.aux             YourDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot
# MyDocument.blg      YourDocument.auxlock         YourDocument.run.xml
# MyDocument.log      YourDocument.bbl             YourDocument.toc
# MyDocument.out      YourDocument.bcf

ls --hide='*.tex' MyDocument.*    # does NOT work with prefix glob!
# MyDocument.aux      MyDocument.bcf  MyDocument.out               MyDocument.tex
# MyDocument.auxlock  MyDocument.blg  MyDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot  MyDocument.toc
# MyDocument.bbl      MyDocument.log  MyDocument.run.xml

ls MyDocument!(.tex|.aux)         # works with (FULL!) prefix
# MyDocument.auxlock  MyDocument.blg  MyDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot
# MyDocument.bbl      MyDocument.log  MyDocument.run.xml
# MyDocument.bcf      MyDocument.out  MyDocument.toc

ls MyDocu*!(.tex|.aux)            # does NOT work w/ partial prefix 
                                  # if * pattern does not terminate (is last before !)
# MyDocument.aux      MyDocument.bcf  MyDocument.out               MyDocument.tex
# MyDocument.auxlock  MyDocument.blg  MyDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot  MyDocument.toc
# MyDocument.bbl      MyDocument.log  MyDocument.run.xml

ls MyDocu*.!(tex|aux)             # does work w/ partial prefix, if * pattern terminates
                                  # (here termination is with dot . coming before ! )
# MyDocument.auxlock  MyDocument.blg  MyDocument.pgf-plot.gnuplot
# MyDocument.bbl      MyDocument.log  MyDocument.run.xml
# MyDocument.bcf      MyDocument.out  MyDocument.toc
```

So, the answer for this case is to use `ls PREFIX*.!(ext1|ext2)`, or in other words: "list files starting with 'PREFIX' and any characters until a dot '.', which is not followed by ext1 or ext2".

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it has the most accurate explanations why the last approach is the correct choice. Thank you for your answer with clear explanation!

Answer (score 10):

```
ls -I*.tex -I*.aux
```

or

```
ls --hide=*.tex --hide=*.aux
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use bash and have the `extglob` shell option set (which is usually the case):

```
ls !(*.tex|*.aux)
```

Comment: This is the one. See this same question over at ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/41783/how-can-i-specify-a-shell-pattern-that-excludes-certain-files

Comment: Or this question at Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670460/move-all-files-except-one

Which is a question by the same user where I already gave the same answer...

Comment: @Sth: Well, you got two upvotes out of it from me at least. (I only remembered the thread on Serverfault, since I learned this trick there.)

Answer (score 0):

you may use:

```
ls | grep -v *.tex | grep -v *.aux
```

Comment: I don't think that does what you think it does. `grep` takes regular expressions as parameters, not shell wildcards. Also, the shell will expand those wildcards first anyway.

Comment: "ls | grep -v .tex | grep -v .aux" seems to work.  (On my machine, ls does not take the -I or --hide flags.)

Comment: You could also use a regex with egrep: `ls | egrep -v '(aux|tex)$'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using zsh with EXTENDED_GLOB option set:

```
pattern~negpattern
```

where 'pattern' is what you want to match, except for anything matching 'negpattern'.

Example:

```
ls -d *~*.mp3
```

will list all the files in your cwd except those ending in '.mp3'.

If you're not using zsh, give it a try, this kind of intelligent expansion is everywhere.